# Using array.index() and string.lower() in the same time

Tags: python-3.x

I have arrays like that :

```py
array_1 = ["The", "radius", "is", "30", "km"]
array_2 = ["The", "second", "radius", "is", "25", "KM"]
```

I need to get the index where unit of radius is. I would like to ignore case in my search.
For ignore case on string, i always work with `lower()` function but here, I don't know how can I use it.

My problem with code looks like that :

```py
index_1 = array_1.index("km") # Result: 4
index_2 = array_2.index("km") # ValueError because "km" not in list.
```

FYI, I work with Python 3.8.

Any idea ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most pythonic way is probably to apply `lower()` on each element of your list, e.g. via a list comprehension:

```
index_1 = [string.lower() for string in array_1].index("km") # outputs 4
index_2 = [string.lower() for string in array_2].index("km") # outputs 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the unit to lower with for loop:

```
for item in array_2:
    if item.lower() == 'km':
        array_2[array_2.index(item)] = 'km'
```

Comment: Thanks, your proposition looks like that of @Théo Rubenach.

Comment: @BastienB Mine does change only 'km' item to lowercase, not every item in the list

Comment: @w8eight A list comprehension does not change items in the list, it creates a new one. Your solution might be better for huge lists if memory usage is a problem though.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

```
def index_ignore_case(array, element):
    element = element.lower()
    for idx, elem in enumerate(array):
        if elem.lower() == element:
            return idx
```

**Solution 2**

```
def index_ignore_case(array, element):
    lower_array = [e.lower() for e in array]
    return lower_array.index(element)
```

**Performance**
[image: Performance Test]
Based on this performance test, you should use solution 2 im most cases. Only when most of the elements are in the first half of the array, you should use solution 1. I think solution 1 is so slow in worst case because python does some optimization when using list compreshion which makes it faster.

(I don't know why there are some irregularities at 6500, maybe the server was under load there)
Test code: https://repl.it/@TechnicBricks/lowerIndexPerformanceTest

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer. I take it for other situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_1 = ["The", "radius", "is", "30", "km"]
array_2 = ["The", "second", "radius", "is", "25", "KM"]

index_1 = list(map(lambda v:v.lower(), array_1)).index("km")
index_2 = list(map(lambda v:v.lower(), array_2)).index("km")
```

Comment: This solution changes every item in the list to lowercase, and this might be undesirable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
index_2 = [i.lower() for i in array_2].index("km")
```